# Is it legal for my mum to share the household's browsing history with an external company without my consent?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, consent

## Background Information

My mum uses lots of different websites for surveys, watching videos and other ways of generating a little bit of cash. However, she uses a particular service to share the entire household's browsing history with another organisation, so that she can earn a little bit extra money. She started doing this without even telling anyone and when I found out, I did not agree with it or consent to it, but she questioned what I have to hide and of course, I did not want to answer that question.

**Is it legal for my mum to share my browsing history without my consent?**

---

### Side Notes

- I am located within England, UK.
- I am 16 years of age.

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: @Moo Is that relevant?

Comment: Very possibly - and what location are you asking about (if in the US, state is important as well)?  Both will have an impact on what law applies here and allow respondents to give better answers.  Your question, while concise and well laid out, is actually quite vague on details which would allow it to be answered appropriately.

Comment: in most jurisdictions, yes.  In the US, a parent can pretty much do whatever they want as long as it isn't abuse..

Comment: @Moo I have added extra information.

Comment: @ScottDunnington I have added extra information.

Comment: A parent has not only the right but also the obligation to protect a minor child. Selling private information about the child for personal profit may be deemed as inappropriate.